# Editor value set in jQuery not passed to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

As the title suggest, I am setting the value of a field using jQuery but on submit, that value is not passed to my controller.

**What I have done**

Part of view

```
 <div class="controls controls col-md-10">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.itemValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @onChange = "calRealAmt()" } })
  </div>

...


<div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label col-md-6">Amount</label>
              <div class="controls col-md-10">
     @if (String.Equals((string)ViewBag.fixedAmount, "Y"))
         {
                //disale the amount field
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)
     }
     else
      {
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control spinner" } }) }
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          </div>
      </div>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calRealAmt() {
        var itemValue = $("#itemValue").val();
        var ivDiv;
        var Ans;
        var calPer = $("#calPer").val(); 
        ivDiv = calPer / 100; 
        Ans = itemValue * ivDiv; 

        $("#amount").attr('value', Ans);
    }
```

As you can see, this is just some simple jquery to calculate the percentage and set it to the amount field. 
Visually the value is set, when I right click and inspect, the value there is also correct, however when I submit the form, the amount variable is 0 in the controller. 
(P.S, if I type in a number it also gets submitted fine.)

Was hoping if I could be assisted in fixing this issue, I am aware of using ajax to submit but that seems a bit of over kill and i'm interested why the value isnt being submitted even if it is set.
**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Addpayment([Bind(Include = "perDescrip,itemValue,cartId_FK,documentNbr,paymentTypeId_FK,amount,r1Value,r2Value,r3Value,r4Value,r5Value")] Transaction trans)
        {
```

Regards

Comment: When you assign value to #amount is it a integer value or decimal?

Comment: Int,  could data type cause that issue?

Comment: If your calculated value is decimal then it will not accepted by your int property

Comment: This does not seem to be the issue. i modified my code to `Ans = Math.round(itemValue * calPer) / 100;` 
the amount is defined as a numeric(12,2).
However still no value appears in my controller.

Comment: which element have the id amount your textbox or hidden field?

Comment: `<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field amount must be a number." data-val-required="The amount field is required." disabled="disabled" id="amount" name="amount" type="text" value="22.2">`

This here, this is the pure textbox when i inspect it.

Comment: see the value 22.2 which is decimal

Comment: No i made an error, account is data type numeric(12,2)

Comment: okay can you check what value is passed to the submit request in Network tab of developer tool?

Comment: Yes I checked, amount is 0 there as well

Comment: Then looks like issue is at html or Javascript. can you log the value on submit event? see what value is getting logged. so did you debug your js?

Comment: @RajeshG the logged value is correct but that value is not being passed to the controller, 0 is still ppassed

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.amount)`   Here you have both editorfor and hiddenfor. Do you need both? Can you remove HiddenFor and try?

Comment: Join this [room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205059/c-team) to discuss further

Comment: `disabled = "disabled"` is the reason why it was not working.

Comment: can you post it as answer here.